# In the following code i have used 2 printf statements.The problem is that iam getting the output as" hi hello hi hello " instead of "hi hello hello"

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Unistd.h>
Void main()
  { Printf("hi");
    fork();
    Printf("hello");
   }
```

`Output: hi hello hi hello`
"But when iam using \n in the printf statements iam getting the output as"

```
Output: hi
        hello
        hello
```

[But \n is  used for displaying statement in new line but why am i getting this difference]
Thank you ...

Comment: C is case sensitive language. Your program is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` buffers its output, and when you `fork`, now the output is in both programs' buffers, so they'll both eventually print it. To fix it, you should force the buffer to be flushed immediately before forking by doing `fflush(stdout)`. You don't see the problem with `\n` because using `\n` also flushes the buffer.